# Collapse vertical borders of adjacent elements?

Tags: html, css

How can I collapse vertical borders of two adjacent elements without removing border-top/border-bottom?

For ex:

```
<style type="text/css">
.bordered {
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
...
<body>
    <div class="bordered">bordered_1</div>
    <div class="bordered">bordered_2</div>
</body>
```

One way i found is to add

```
margin-top:-1px;
margin-bottom:-1px;
```

to .bordered. But this way if i change border thickness i also must change margin-top and margin-bottom.
The other way is to set:

```
body {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.bordered {
    display:table-row;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

It appears to have good browser compatibility(tested on IE 9, FF, Chrome), but it's a hacky sort of code.
Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: what's the problem in using a *hacky way* to do a *hacky job* ?

Comment: why you don't want to remove some border? to me it seems less *hacky* than using display: table on the body.

Comment: An other solution can be `margin-top:-1px;` with a js generated value

Comment: What "hacky job"? I asked a question about how to solve the task and i don't  see something unusual in it. I don't want to remove borders because i use ".bordered" for any element that should have border and these element may not be adjacent to the other element with border.

Comment: Negative margins are more hacky than table layout IMO, considering this sort of thing is how table layout *works*, whereas you have to jump through a number of hoops to cater to negative margins. The simplest way, as mentioned, would be to just specify a border on one side for all but one of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

For the limited scope of your example, you could simply specify that an element with class `bordered` should not have a `border-top` if it is preceded immediately by an element with that same class, using the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), `+`:

```css
.bordered {
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
.bordered + .bordered {
    border-top:0 none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered">bordered_1</div>
<div class="bordered">bordered_2</div>
```

Comment: This works great, but only with zero vertical margins.

Comment: That’s why I prefixed this whole answer with, _“For the limited scope of your example”_ … And if you include vertical margins in your requirements, then I don’t actually see how “collapsing borders” would make sense under those conditions? What would a “collapsed” border between two elements look like, if there’s a margin separating those two elements?

Comment: If one of the elements have margin then they would not collapse and would be rendered with separate borders, just like table cells in table with border-collapse:separate. The point is: sometimes two elements are adjacent and have no margins- in this case their borders should collapse. But when at lesast one of them have vertical margin or they are not adjacent- in this case each of them should be rendered with it's own border. Basically try to imagine that all block elements have the implementation of "border-collapse" css property.

Comment: Ah, OK. Well, no, that doesn’t work with this method – there is no way of “querying” whether or not two elements are separated by a margin. And making them display as `table-row` elements, so that you can make use of `border-collapse` would not really work in this scenario either, because `margin-top`/`-bottom` are not applicable to such elements as per CSS 2.1 specification.

Comment: But I think whether or not those elements get margins in the first place must be based on some sort of content-related decision(?) – so that giving them certain classes accordingly should not be out of the question. And then those classes could be used to format them with or without borders where necessary.